# Create a new DialogFragment from another DialogFragment instantiated in another context

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I am developing an Android library to ask the users of an app to give a rating on the Play Store.

The UX of the library consists in a few dialogs. Depending on the answer to the first question I might need to dismiss the current dialog, to show another dialog or to take the user to the Play Store.

Everything works nice unless I rotate the screen in the middle of the process.

I tried to solve my issues with the use of fragments. With fragments I am not losing anymore the state of the dialogs with the rotation but I am having troubles instantiating the second DialogFragment. The problem is that, after a rotation, the context of the first DialogFragment is no more active and it has no way to retrieve the new context. That results in exceptions every time I try to instantiate the new DialogFragment.

Is there any way I could solve this issue?

Thinking again at the problem, it seems that my design choice was wrong but I am not very experienced in Android development. Every advice will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the listener pattern. Define an interface in each dialog and send clicks back to the activity. Let it create the dialogs. 
[see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)

Also, if you need a context in the fragments, just call getActivity(), don't create an unnecessary context variable that could later give back an activity that's already gone. I hope that helps. I can't give a better answer without some code to see what's going wrong in this specific situation.